# Can't save or properly dial phonenumber, too big ios

Tags: ios, core-data, storyboard, nsnumber, nsobject

Hi when I try to save a phonenumber with this line to a coredata element

```
            [newLead setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.cellTextField.text doubleValue] ] forKey:@"cell"];
```

Then I load it with this

```
    [self.cellTextField setText:[[self.lead valueForKey:@"cell"] stringValue]];
```

It works but if the number is like 905666777 , that number is too big and i get 2147483647

How can i make it use a 905 number?

also when i dial the number using

```
     NSURL *telUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@"cell"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telUrl];
```

It only dials the first 3 digits 214, how can i make it dial all the digits

Thank you

Comment: The first line should read `[newLead setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.cellTextField.text integerValue] ] forKey:@"cell"];` with **integerValue** instead of doubleValue

Comment: @bachonk yeah i caught that and fixed it but still

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're saving a phone number as a numeric value, so you're running into limits on numeric types. There's no reason to do this this-- you should be using a string. You'll never do math on the phone number, for example. Any fetches you might do (for example finding phone numbers with a specific area code) will be more difficult with a numeric type than with a string.

Comment: Agreed.  Phone numbers are not simply numbers and should never be treated as such.  International numbers start with `+` and may contain parentheses, and many phone numbers contain leading zeroes that must be preserved.